Unable to boot into GUI on Ubuntu, stuck at tty1
I'm encountering an issue with my Ubuntu system where it boots into tty1 instead of the graphical user interface (GUI) after startup. Here are the steps I've taken and the details of the problem:
Every time I boot Ubuntu, it bypasses the GUI and loads into tty1 instead. I'm unable to access the desktop environment
Steps I've taken:
I ran sudo apt update, but it failed at the last step. I attempted sudo apt-get upgrade, which also failed at the last step. I tried to recover the system, but it didn't resolve the issue.


You've tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, however the picture link you've provided shows 22.04. Have you recently release-upgraded?  or why the difference?  Is this a different system to the one you think it is? or why the difference?  If you have a problem with sudo apt update then that may also be related, and we cannot read details we're not provided.

Welcome to Askubuntu. We need the errors to know how and why it's failing. "failing at the last step" doesn't really tell us anything of value so please provide the actual error message. The error message often includes the exact details that tell us what the solution is.
